# How/When to remove child elements to clear search result?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

Trying to clear my search result after I submit a new API call. Tried implementing `gallery.remove(galleryItems);` at different points but to no avail.

A bit disappointed I couldn't figure it out but happy I was able to get a few async functions going. Anyway, here's the code:

```
'use strict';

const form = document.querySelector('#searchForm');
const gallery = document.querySelector('.flexbox-container');
const galleryItems = document.getElementsByClassName('flexbox-item');

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userSearch = form.elements.query.value;   // grab user input
    const res = await getRequest(userSearch); // async func that returns a fully parsed Promise
    tvShowMatches(res.data); // looks for matches, creates and appends name + image;
    form.elements.query.value = '';
});

const getRequest = async (search) => {
    const config = { params: { q: search } };
    const res = await axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows', config);
    return res;
};

const tvShowMatches = async (shows) => {
    for (let result of shows) {
        if (result.show.image) {
            // new div w/ flexbox-item class + append to gallery
            const tvShowMatch = document.createElement('DIV')
            tvShowMatch.classList.add('flexbox-item');
            gallery.append(tvShowMatch);

            // create, fill & append tvShowName to tvShowMatch
            const tvShowName = document.createElement('P');
            tvShowName.textContent = result.show.name;
            tvShowMatch.append(tvShowName);

            // create, fill & append tvShowImg to tvShowMatch
            const tvShowImg = document.createElement('IMG');
            tvShowImg.src = result.show.image.medium;
            tvShowMatch.append(tvShowImg);
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `gallery.remove(galleryItems);` consider resetting `gallery.innerHTML` to an empty string whenever a `submit` event occurs

Like this:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  gallery.innerHTML = ''; // Reset here
  const userSearch = form.elements.query.value;   // grab user input
  const res = await getRequest(userSearch); // async func that returns a fully parsed Promise
  tvShowMatches(res.data); // looks for matches, creates and appends name + image;
  form.elements.query.value = '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So obvious when you point it out. Not sure why I didn't think of it.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. Do you mind giving it an upvote as well? @Vayl

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it.. you were close.

```
const galleryItems = document.getElementsByClassName('flexbox-item');

// to remove
galleryItems.forEach(elem => elem.remove() );
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work for me I'm afraid.